# Folder inside docker container instance disappears when assigning multiple volumes in docker command line

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount use two volumes:
/app/node_modules
*and*
/$(pwd):/app
*So I run this command in my terminal*

```
docker run -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):/app user/my-project
```

If I understand correctly, if I use a directory without a colon (`-v /app/node_modules`), the directory will persist in the created docker instance.
Otherwise, if I use it with a colon (`-v /$(pwd):app`), the docker instance will use the files inside my project folder. I want to do this so I can make changes to my source code without having to re-run docker.

However, if I use `-v /$(pwd):/app` the node_modules inside the docker instance disappears.

Also, please do note that I do not have node_modules in my project directory.

Ultimately, I want to be able to make changes to the code without having to re-run docker. If there is any other better approach to this, please let me know.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app

# Copy dependency list.
COPY package.json ./

# Install dependencies. This creates node_modules folder
RUN npm install

# Copy source code.
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I then run:

```
docker run -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):/app user/my-project
```

Logs and errors that I get:

```
> client@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-19T06_22_28_159Z-debug.log
```

When I inspect the file system with `docker run -it user/my-project sh` I could see that node_modules is not there.

Comment: Just mount the directory containing source code in container's /app directory like this: `docker run -v $(pwd):/app user/my-project`. Is this an option?

Comment: Are you sure your original command is `docker run -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):app user/my-project` ? It should not work and fail with `invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'app' mount path must be absolute`

Comment: @PierreB. Sorry, it was `/$(pwd):/app`. Fixed now.

Comment: @leopal yes I did that with `docker run -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):/app user/my-project`. But the problem is, since I do not have `node_modules` in my project directory, docker is removing the `node_modules` in the created instance.

Comment: But `-v /app/node_modules` if I am not mistaken just creates that directory inside container, does not offer any persistence. Containers are ephemeral, thus you should not rely on them for persistent data. IMO, mounting containers `/app` dir to host's source dir is the simplest option for changes in source code to be applied immediately to container. Why do you need node_modules to be mounted explicitly?

Comment: @RamilAmparo A comment for your last edit, you should inspect a stopped container not an image to determine what's happening with your mounts. `docker run -it user/my-project sh` obviously contains only actions performed in the Dockerfile. You haven't create a `/app/node_modules` directory thus it is totally normal that it is not exist. Volumes are set up at runtime.

Comment: @leopal I do not want my project directory to have `node_modules` that's why I have `RUN npm install` in my Dockerfile. However, if I use `-v \$(pwd):/app`, the `node_modules` inside the container is removed (is it because I do not have node_modules in my project directory?).  I just thought `-v /app/node_modules` prevents it from getting removed.

Comment: @leopal Thanks for the heads up. However, I still think that `node_modules` in the container is getting removed, since if I do not use `-v /$(pwd):/app` the container does not throw any errors.

Comment: Ohh now I understand what you are saying. My bad. Your initial command is almost correct, `docker run -v /app/node_modules -v  $(pwd):/app user/my-project`. I removed leading slash from `$(pwd)`. Make sure you are executing this from the correct host directory in order `pwd` to reflect the desired dir. Preferably provide the absolute host's path. After your source code changes will be immediately available to the container.

Comment: @leopol the leading slash is because of git bash conversion issue because I am using windows. https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/673#issuecomment-479374041 I am pretty sure that was not the issue though. I will try again later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196694/discussion-between-ramil-amparo-and-leopal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it has something to do with git bash.

I have tried running this command in windows powershell and it works perfectly fine.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v `pwd`:/app ramilamparo/car-rental-management-client
```